# Ejabberd with using java EE

Tags: jakarta-ee, xmpp, ejabberd, smack

I am trying to implement mobile clients with using ejabberd XMPP server, 
I want to use Java EE to communicate between clients and ejabberd, such as sending push notifications vs.
One of the most important problem is registring the clients with Java EE,
How can I connect the Java EE and ejjabberd?

Thanks,

Comment: Java EE has no relation to XMPP, do you mean Java SE?

Comment: Actually, I am trying to send push notifications both IOS ans Android platforms, so I need to detect offline messages on ejabberd and send push notifications with java platform, All in all, I am trying to implement push notification server for ejabberd with using java.

Comment: @Poyraz did u get the solution for this...because I am looking for the same.

Comment: You can try to use smack api.